# How to XOR 2 strings proper in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xor

I am currently having issues with XOR'ing two strings in python where it is returning gibberish results.

Based on research I derived the method in XORing is as follows : -

```
def xor_strings(s,t):
    """xor two strings together"""
    return "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s,t))
```

So I proceed to XOR two string as below :

```
c1 = xor_strings('cisco12300000000','46608024c8f48fd0')
print c1
```

The resulting string came back with gibberish as shown in the image below :
[image]

Am i doing something wrong here with the XOR operation  ?

In summary im trying to generate a string similar to freeradius hashing of userpassword with shared secret and authenticator IV

EDIT: This is not a duplicate as the attempted solution return gibberish hence the question

Comment: What's the definition of XOR on a string? Typically the XOR op only makes sense on a boolean or binary data.

Comment: What does it mean to "XOR a string"? You're coming up with gibberish because what you're doing is gibberish. If the string is a string representation of something that you want to "XOR", you need to convert the string to that something first then do your XOR'ing...

Comment: how do i do that ? convert to binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gibberish is what you get when you XOR.  But if you XOR the gibberish with the original value you get the original string back:

```
#!python2
def xor_strings(s,t):
    """xor two strings together"""
    return "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s,t))

c1 = xor_strings('cisco12300000000','46608024c8f48fd0')
print repr(c1) # To see the unprintable bytes as escape codes
c1 = xor_strings(c1,'46608024c8f48fd0')
print c1
```

Output:

```
'W_ESW\x01\x00\x07S\x08V\x04\x08VT\x00'
cisco12300000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming, by looking at the code you have written that you want to XOR corresponding characters(their ASCII values). 
So, `'abcde','fghijk'`  => `[97,98,99,100,101],[102,103,104,105,106]` are their ASCII values. 
XORing corresponding characters gives `[7, 5, 11, 13, 15]`

Your code does produce the above array. If this is what you intended to do, your code is correct. Yes, it is.

The reason what you see, looks like 'gibberish' is that:
[image]

Look at the character column of the low ord() values. They give characters that look like gibberish on your screen. For example, the above array `[7, 5, 11, 13, 15]` gives `['\x07', '\x05', '\x0b', '\r', '\x0f']` which when printed gives what looks like gibberish. Same holds for your set of two strings too.